# Laravel 5 Auth::user() is empty everywhere except index() function and blade template

Tags: laravel-5, middleware

I've been trying for some time to figure this out, but no solution I found was conclusive. Basically I'm trying to retrieve a list of clients based on the user logged in, but I cannot retrieve the user object anywhere in the controller except the `index()` function where is returns the view, and also the blade template that displays the logged in user's name.

This is my ClientController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Models\Client;
use App\Http\Requests\GetClientsRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class ClientController extends Controller
{
    protected $user;
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

       $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
           $this->user = Auth::user();

           return $next($request);
       });
    }

    /**
     * Show the clients page.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        Log::info("client user: " . print_r($this->user, 1));
        return view('page');
    }

    public function getClients()
    {
        $currentUser = Auth::user();

        if ($currentUser) {
            $clients = Client::with('account')
                    ->where('user_id', $currentUser->account)
                    ->get();

            $collection = collect($clients);

            return response($collection->toArray());
        }
    }
}
```

The Log in the index function prints out the user object no problem - but when it's called in the `getClients()` function, it's empty. I also tried using this in the `__construct()`:

```
$this->middleware('auth');
```

As per the Laravel template I was using, but whenever I call the `getClients` API route I always get a 401 Unauthorized error.

Here is my `api.php` routes file (although only currently using the getClients call) :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::get('welcome-message', 'DashboardController@getWelcomeMessage');

Route::prefix('clients')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'ClientController@getClients');
    Route::get('/{clientId}', 'ClientController@getClient');
    Route::post('/', 'ClientController@postCreateClient');
    Route::put('/{clientId}', 'ClientController@putUpdateClient');
});
```

And my `web.php` routes file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/


Auth::routes();

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('dashboard');
Route::get('/clients', 'ClientController@index')->name('clients');
```

The system knows I'm logged in, because I wouldn't even be able to visit the client dashboard at all, so I don't understand why I cannot get a result from `Auth::user()` in the function - unless I'm using the middleware incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the `auth:api` middleware to allow [API authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport).

To do so, add this middleware to your API route, omit in that case to add middleware in the `__constructor`.

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'clients',
    'middleware' => ['auth:api']
], function(){
    Route::get('/', 'ClientController@getClients');
    // ... etc
});
```

Make sure that you have a valid access token to access your API. When using your API with a JS front-end, [read about it](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript) in the Laravel docs.

Note that 'web' authentication (middleware: `auth`) uses a different **mechanism** than API authentication (middleware: `auth:api`) to authenticate users.

Comment: I'm still getting a 401 Unauthorized error. I tried installing that Laravel Passport, but nothing seemed to work, even though I followed the documentation. But you are correct in the sense that the user is only authenticated through 'auth' and not 'auth:api' so I have no idea what to do :(